# Looking for a Github.com keyboard shortcuts list

Tags: github, keyboard-shortcuts

I was looking for keyboard shortcuts for Github.com.

Ressource already found: http://goo.gl/WTHcdl.

Do you know any other Github.com keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

The official way to access to Github.com keyboard shortcuts is to simply hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>.